# Python3: Adding equal elements together from json format

Tags: json, python-3.x, list

```
Data = [{'Ferrari': 51078}, {'Volvo': 83245, 'Ferrari': 70432, 'Skoda': 
29264, 'Lambo': 862},
{'Ferrari': 306415, 'Jeep': 4025, 'Saab': 2708, 'Lexus': 161}, {'Fiat': 
27583, 'Maserati': 11030, 'Renault': 3194, 'Volvo': 259, 'Skoda': 164}, 
{'Ferrari': 2313172, 'Renault': 2475},
{'Volvo': 198671}, {'Volvo': 15762}]
```

I want to add together the numbers for each car, so I get the total amount for each element (the numbers below aren't accurate with the Data and just an example):
    Ferrari: 152455
    Volvo: 13515
    Skoda: 1532
    Lambo: 4366
    Renault: 4262
    Maserati: 2345
    Lexus: 235
    Jeep: 124
    Saab: 15

I've tried with sum(), append it to new lists, collections and many other potential solutions, but I just cannot get this one right. I'm searching for a general solution not only applicable to my problem, so if I change my dataset and hence the numbers and cars, it needs to work also for the new Data.

I'm using Python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict`. The code below iterates over the list of dicts. Then taking out a random key-value pair until each dict is empty and summing the results.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'Ferrari': 51078},
        {'Volvo': 83245, 'Ferrari': 70432, 'Skoda': 29264, 'Lambo': 862},
        {'Ferrari': 306415, 'Jeep': 4025, 'Saab': 2708, 'Lexus': 161},
        {'Fiat': 27583, 'Maserati': 11030, 'Renault': 3194, 'Volvo': 259, 'Skoda': 164},
        {'Ferrari': 2313172, 'Renault': 2475},
        {'Volvo': 198671},
        {'Volvo': 15762}]

output = defaultdict(int)

for d in data:
    while d:
        k, v = d.popitem()
        output[k] += v

print(output)
```

Outputs

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Ferrari': 2741097,
                            'Lambo': 862,
                            'Skoda': 29428,
                            'Volvo': 297937,
                            'Lexus': 161,
                            'Saab': 2708,
                            'Jeep': 4025,
                            'Renault': 5669,
                            'Maserati': 11030,
                            'Fiat': 27583})
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked super! I was first a bit confused with the line `k, v = d.popitem()` but think I now finally got the idea of that.